# tensorflow run function doesn't return numpy when running on pytest

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, batch-normalization

getting the next error when running batch_norm with slim tensorflow and trying to print the numpy result:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'
```

the code is:

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(1, 2, 2, 32), dtype=tf.float32))
y = slim.batch_norm(x)
sess = tf.Session()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
y_np = y.eval(session=sess)
x_np = x.eval(session=sess)
print("x\n" + str(x_np))
print("y\n" + str(y_np))
```

I also tried

```
sess = tf.Session()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
y_np, x_np = sess.run([y, x])
print("x\n" + str(x_np))
print("y\n" + str(y_np))
```

any suggestions ?

**update:**

it turns out the if fails to print only when running in pytest (which I did). When running only through python the printing is succeeded.

Comment: what is the tensorflow version ?

Comment: the version is 1.7.